# Rails if statement syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I've written the following ERB and am getting a syntax error at the question mark. This helper function from devise currently evaluates as false. What have I missed?

```
<%= if user_signed_in? %>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= end %>
```

Comment: Note that '?' and '!' are **valid** characters in method names.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this :

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```

If you do <%= ... %>, it will try to output the thing you put between the tags. But, if you do <% ... %>, then no output is processed, just the code is evaluated. If this is not working, then there is probably something wrong with your user_signed_in? helper method.

Answer (score 27):

`<%=` will try to output your `user_signed_in?` helper, so try:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```

or even better (and less confusing):

```
<%= render 'form' if user_signed_in? %>
```

Comment: Thanks for describing the difference between `<%=` and `<%`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```