# Ruby on Rails - Conditional table coloring in erb template file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

```
<% @s2_pmt_transact.each do |s2_pmt_transact| %>
<% if (s2_pmt_transact.key = 7) %>
<tr style="background-color:#EAEAEA">
<% else %>
<tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
<% end %>
```

I would like the cell coloring to be based on value of key as in the code above. But all values of key (7 and above) are printed just fine - but color coding seems to be just #EAEAEA for all of them. How can I enforce conditional coloring?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check the value of an HTML input field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706035/rails-if-statement-syntax#6706127

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional is wrong, needs to use `==` not `=` which is an assignment and explains why all are grey.

```
<% @s2_pmt_transact.each do |s2_pmt_transact| %>
 <% if s2_pmt_transact.key == 7 %>
  <tr style="background-color:#EAEAEA">
 <% else %>
  <tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
 <% end %>
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks much!!